# Avoiding null pointer on failed join

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, grails

I have my domain class, with a named query:

```
class Atendimento implements Serializable {
    ...
    Funcionario funcionario

    static mapping = {
        ...
        funcionario column: 'FUNCODIGO', sqlType: 'int'
    }

    static namedQueries = {
         atendimentosPorData { data ->
             data.clearTime();
             eq('dataHora', data)
             isNotNull('funcionario')
         }
    }
}
```

Application run on a legacy database with no FK constraints. 
The problem: there are some "broken" relationships, some "Atendimento" have a FUNCODIGO on the database, but there is no "Funcionario" with this identifier.
I can query without problem, but when i send this to a view, like this

```
${fieldValue(bean: atendimentoInstance, field: "funcionario")}
```

I got a error saying that grails could not find "Funcionario" with id: xxxxx.
The *isNotNUll* on the criteria doesn't work because the column have data, but it fails when you try to resolve the join.

Is there a way to prevent the join on the "problematic" columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ignoreNotFound` to tell Grails ignore the missing references

[Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/ignoreNotFound.html)

**ignoreNotFound**:

> Specifies how foreign keys that reference missing rows are handled in many-to-one relationships.

```
class LegacyCdDomain {
    String title
    Thumbnail thumbnail

    static mapping = {
        thumbnail ignoreNotFound: true
    }
}
```