# Why is gorm/hibernate eager loading? Getting "no row with the given identifier..."

Tags: hibernate, grails, lazy-loading, grails-orm

EDIT: problem solved by comments...

we have such standard code for domain classes in Grails:

```
class Foo {...}

class Bar { 
   Foo foo
}
```

Without any configuration, my undestanding is that while Loading objects of Bar, Foo is lazy loaded. Means that if I am doing this:

```
def barList = Bar.all
```

the Foo's of all bar objects are not loaded and also that if the Foo object doesn't exist anymore in the database, Bar.all won't fail due to the lazy loading, but fail when the missing object is tried to read.

However, in our setup Foo is part of a different database and entries might be deleted. So, there is no foreign key in Bar for the Foo relation. If that happens such Bar objects should be ignored. So my approach would be merely:

```
def barList = Bar.all
barList.each {
   try {
       // do something a.o. with the foo relation
   }
   catch (ObjectNotFoundException e) {
      // place some warnings in the log, but continue with next
   }
}
```

Sadly, already the Bar.all fails with ObjectNotFoundException which means that GORM/Hibernate is already joining with the Foo table.

But why?

Comment: You can tell grails not to throw exception using `ignoreNotFound`[see if this post helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365393/avoiding-null-pointer-on-failed-join/18365619#18365619)

Comment: Yeah, that helps a bit to avoid Exception handling. I also found out that the Exception was thron on a different relation where eager loading was explicitly configured. Sadly, GORM is not displaying the SQL when an error occured. (except SQL.DEBUG is true, of course)